# Is Active-record callbacks - after_save and after_commit are thread-safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have two models - ModelA and ModelB. When we create/save an instance of ModelA, we need to bulk inserts for ModelB (requires ModelA id, no association between ModelA and ModelB).We are doing this by running a background job in after_save callback of ModelA.

The problem is that, the bulk inserts  for ModelB are not correct as ModelA is not permanently saved in the database. So we decided to use after_commit. But we also need instance state (which is in after_save) of ModelA. We assign this state to one variable in after_save and accessing it in after_commit.

Is active-records after_Save and after_commit callbacks are thread-safe on current instance of ModelA?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your associations are:

```
ModelA has_many :modelBs
ModelB belongs_to :modelA
```

Instead of running the save for modela then running the saves for modelb you should do it all in one transaction, rails does most of this for you.

```
@modelA = ModelA.new(params[:modelA])

@modelA.modelBs.new(params[:modelB].values)

@modelA.save
```

this is of course if you follow rails parameters conventions

```
<form action=(modela_url) post>
<input name='modelA[`attr`]' ...
<input name='modelA[`attr`]' ...

<!-- multiple sub model objects
<input name='modelB[1][`attr`]' ...
<input name='modelB[2][`attr`]' ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is one misunderstanding. I have updated the question. While inserting records for ModelB, I want id of instance of ModelA and there is no association between ModelA and ModelB. We are running one background service for bulk insertions.